# Take drugs or do drugs?

Tags: meaning, expressions

In school we learn that if you want to express someone is consuming drugs you say they are *taking drugs*. In some rap songs however, the phrase *doing drugs* is used. Is there a difference in meaning between those two phrases or are they similar?

Comment: You **take** prescription drugs; you never **do** them. You may take or do the other kind.

Comment: Evidence of [research](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/do_drugs) would be useful, I think.

Comment: I would also add that '*doing drugs'* connotes some sort of addiction to the substance rather than just controlled use.

Comment: @Silenus - Once again today I must disagree. My patients don't **do** the drugs I prescribe for them. (How silly does "He's doing Cipro for his pyelonephritis" sound? Yet, "He was *doing* heroin, but bought some laced with fentanyl, causing him to OD." But it might be an AmE thing.

Comment: @medica, again carelessness on my part. I was assuming the drugs under discussion were illegal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Doing drugs* is almost always applied to indicate recurring recreational/[illicit drug use](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/do_drugs).

*Taking drugs* is used for that case, but also covers non-recurring and medical drug usage as well.

You're not "doing drugs" if Aderall is part of your medical treatment for ADHD.  You might be described as "doing drugs" if you regularly take Aderall for recreational purposes.